# Wordpress seach - How to search from title or meta key ? Get both results

Tags: wordpress, meta

I am fetching from this code.  If I search "google" then fetch all the posts those title or content contains "google" and fetch those posts also their meta value is 'google'.

```
$search = $_POST['s'];
$meta['meta_query'][] =  array(
    'key'       => 'keyword_custom',
    'value'     => $search,
    'compare'   => 'LIKE',
);
$arg = array(
    'post_type'      => 'abc',
    's' => $search,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'meta_query'     => $meta['meta_query'],
);
$data = get_posts($arg);
```

So If 3 posts have 'google' in the title then will fetch 3 posts and 2 posts have meta value 'google' then fetch these 2 posts also.
So total 5 posts will fetch

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform 2 get_posts, one for title/content and one for post_meta, and then merge the two results.